# R Ports For Mobile Devices

Tags: r, mobile, port

I'm learning **[R](http://r-project.org)** and like the language very much because of its flexibility, but I want to know:

- Are there any ports of **[R](http://r-project.org)** for mobile devices?
- Where can I get them?

Comment: You may want to edit your bullet list, it's not really aligned.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to improve my question.

Comment: No problem, oh and it is 'where can I get them' not 'they'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has been ported to a number of devices.  Learning to use a search engine (as has been suggested to Nathan many times) may be beneficial -- and [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org) (using the 'support lists' tab) almost immediately leads me to

- [R on Sharp Zaurus](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-December/062659.html) post from 2004
- [R on iPhone](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2008-March/004687.html) post from 2008 confirming you can build it, albeit sans GUI
- [More on R on iPhone](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e8/devel/09/10/0142.html) in the context of an *R on Android* question

Nathan, may I suggest that you do a bit more homework and learn to Google first?

Comment: I've searched on Google, but is difficult to search as we got many wrong links. I've searched for: `R+Language+Mobile`

Comment: What you search on Google when you need something of **R**?

Comment: Try the rseek.org site I pointed out.  On Google itself, I sometimes do 'someterm r-help' or 'someterm site:r-project.org'.

Comment: Here are two other 'persistent searches'--which along w/ the one mentioned by Dirk above, are the three i know of and use fairly often--one is a Google Custom Search from Dan Goldstein (http://www.dangoldstein.com/search_r.html). The other hits the R Site and drills right down to the bedrock: "[it allows] you to search the contents of the R functions, package vignettes, task views, and R-help mail archives." (http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/search.html)